# How to install a wireless connection on my netbook?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have an HP 1110NR netbook. It uses wireless (wifi)  only.
It does not have a cable (wire) connection.
How can I install Ubuntu and connect to my wifi router?
The wireless does not work because there does not seem to
be drivers for it in Ubuntu when i install it.
It seems to be looking for a wired connection only.
I do not know what to do.

Comment: The [specifications](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c01661358) say it does have a LAN port. What exactly is your laptop model?

Comment: Hi It is an HP mini 1110NR and there is definitely no wlan connection on it.

Comment: [Are you really sure?](http://www.notebookreview.com/shared/picture.asp?f=40505) Check [front left corner.](http://www.notebookreview.com/shared/picture.asp?f=40499) I cant find any version of 1110NR that does not have a RJ45 port. Could you mention what is your wifi module.

Comment: In case you don't have the LAN port and your wifi card is not supported, what I'd suggest is to get a USB Wifi dongle (a Linksys for example) that'll run from the start with no hassle.

Comment: I have two different wifi dongles. Haven't used them in a couple of years. I dig them out and give them a try. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Or, even better,identify your internal wireless device and install its driver!! Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lspci -nn | rep 0280